# Why the colorbar is not normalized (0 to 1)? How to force it?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, visualization, confusion-matrix

I am plotting a confusion matrix. I have used the function from ScikitLearn. But I do not know why the colorbar does not have a range from 0 to 1. Is there a way to force it?

```
import itertools
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, title='Confusion matrix RF', cmap=plt.cm.viridis):
plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap) 
plt.title(title)
plt.colorbar() 
tick_marks = np.arange(len(np.unique(y))) 

plt.xticks(tick_marks, rotation=90)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(['s'+lab for lab in (ax.get_xticks()+1).astype(str)])
plt.yticks(tick_marks)
ax.set_yticklabels(['s'+lab for lab in (ax.get_yticks()+1).astype(str)])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')




cm_imp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
cm_imp_normalized = cm_imp.astype('float') / cm_imp.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] 
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6)) 
plot_confusion_matrix(cm_imp_normalized)
plt.show() 
print("")
print("")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the color range using the `vmin, vmax` arguments to `imshow`.

```
plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```